# Minimalistic geospatial searching solution for Python

Tags: python, geocoding, geospatial

I am looking for a minimalistic solution for doing basic geospatial search in Python.
We have a dataset of roughly 10 k locations and we need to solve the find the all locations within a radius of N kilometers from a given location. I am not looking for explicit database with geospatial support. I hope to get around another external solution. Is there something that would use Python only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) seems to be a good solution. Its description seems to correspond to what you're looking for :

> [*Shapely*] It lets you do PostGIS-ish stuff outside the context of a database using Python.

It is based on [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/), which a widely used C++ library.

[Here](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#spatial-data-model) is a link to the documentation

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.spatial` has a kd-tree implementation that might be the most popular in Python.

Answer (score 0):

A self made solution without any external modules could be something like this:

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[22.22, 33.33],
                  [08.00, 05.00],
                  [03.12, 05.00],
                  [09.00, 08.00],
                  [-02.5, 03.00],
                  [0.00, -01.00],
                  [-10.0,-10.00],
                  [12.00, 12.00],
                  [-4.00, -6.00]])

r = 10.0   # Radius withing the points should lie
xm = 3     # Center x coordinate
ym = 8     # Center y coordinate

points_i = points[((points[:,0] - xm)**2 + (points[:,1] - ym)**2)**(1/2.0) < r]
```

points_i contains those points which lie within the radius. This solution requires the data to be in a numpy array which is to my knowledge also a very fast way to go trough large data sets as oppose to for loops. I guess this solution is pretty much minimalistic. The plot below shows the outcome with the data given in the code.

[image]

Comment: This linear algorithm might work okay for OP's 10k dataset, but is much less efficient than the techniques usually applied within this domain.